# How to choose axis value in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am a new user to numpy and I was using numpy [delete](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), where it mention that to delete horizontal row we should use axis=0 but in other documentation of numpy [glossary](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/glossary.html), it says horizontal axis is 1. It would be great if someone can let me know what is wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 6):

An array is a systematic way of structuring numbers in grids of any dimensionality. The grid directions have labels, and these labels come from a convention of how new dimensions are added to a grid.

**Here's the convention:**

The simplest such grid is a 0-dimensional (0D) array, which has **`no axes`** and can only hold a scalar. This is a 0D array:

```
42
```

If we start putting scalars into a list we get a 1D array. This new grid only has one axis, and if we want to label that axis with a number, we better start with something simple - like **`axis=0`**! A 1D array could be:

```
# ----0--->
 [42, π, √2]
```

Now we want to create an array of 1D arrays, which will give us a 2D array. The horizontal axis will still be 0, but the new vertical axis will get the next lowest number we know, **`axis=1`**. Here's what it could look like:

```
# ----0---->
[[42, π,  √2],  # |
 [1,  2,   3],  # 1
 [10, 20, 30]]  # V
```

The true beauty is that this generalizes to infinity. If we need a box of numbers we'd create a 3D array by stacking 2D arrays, and the direction that traces the depth of the box would naturally have to be **`axis=2`**. If we wanted a 4D array, we would just make a list of boxes (3D arrays), and call every box using an index along **`axis=3`**. This can go on forever.

**In NumPy:**

Any function/method that takes an `axis`-argument uses this convention. For a 2D array this means that doing something like `np.delete(X, [1, 2, 3], axis=0)` will iterate over arrays extruded along the 0'th axis, to return `X` without rows 1, 2 and 3. The same logic applies for getting values from an array.

```
X[rows_along_0th_axis, columns_along_1st_axis, ..., vectors_along_nth_axis]
```

Comment: Nice! However, the post should be clarified as it could be confusing on numpy. There are 2 points needed to be revised. First about the convention: the only case in which `axis=0` corresponds to iterating over columns is when array is a single list (e.g. `np.array([1,2,3,4])`). In general, `axis` corresponds to actual dimension over which to iterate. E.g., `axis=0` allows iterating over rows while `axis=1` over columns. the shape of a matrix is `(num_rows,num_cols)`. Second, is the access to the `numpy` array: over a matrix rows can be accessed with indices_axis_0, and columns indices_axis_1.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You have a point. Can you explain what you mean by "Second, is the access to the numpy array: over a matrix rows can be accessed with indices_axis_0, and columns indices_axis_1."?

Comment: With the convention that you described `X[index_on_1st_axis, index_on_0th_axis]` is correct, however, looking at the meaning of `axis` in numpy it should be the contrary, namely `X[index_on_0th_axis, index_on_1st_axis]`. Indeed take for example `np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])`, its shape is (3,4) so on axis 0 the max index is 2 (rows) and on axis 1 the max index is 3 (columns). This clarification is due to the first point in my comment.

Answer (score 5):

Taking from the links that you provided, here the excerpts from numpy [delete](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) and [glossary](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/glossary.html) that probably caused you some confusions and the clarification in the following.

1. Excerpt

> ```
> >>> arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
> >>> arr
> array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
>        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
>        [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
> >>> np.delete(arr, 1, 0)
> array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
>        [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
> ```

---

2. Excerpt

> the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the
>   second running horizontally across columns (axis 1)

---

I think the confusion derives from the words *vertically* and *horizontally* in the second excerpt.
What the second excerpt means is that by setting `axis` it is possible to decide over which dimension to move. For example, in a 2d matrix, `axis=0` corresponds to iterating over the rows (thus moving vertically over the array), while `axis=1` corresponds 
to iterating over columns (so moving horizontally over the array). It does not say that `axis=1` corresponds to the horizontal axis as the OP understood.

The `delete` function follows the above description, as indeed, by using `np.delete(arr, 1, axis=0)`, the function iterates over the rows, and deletes the row with index 1. If, instead, columns should be deleted, then `axis=1`. For example, on the same array `arr`

```
>>> np.delete(arr, [0,1,4], axis=1)
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 7,  8],
       [11, 12]])
```

in which `delete` iterates over the columns, and the columns with indices 0, 1  are deleted, and nothing else is deleted as column with index 4 does not exist.

Comment: Clear and direct. Nice.